# Full screen layouts with proper sections

Tags: html, css

There are definitely various methods to have a div cover an entire screen with a full screen image in its background, but mostly all of them would adopt `min-height:100%` and `background-size: cover` property, what this would do is, if some other section, like footer/header is placed, it generally "floats"above" that full screen div.

Like this
[image]

Left image is what presently most solutions do. Right one is what should ideally be good.

One solution is to use `vh` units.

Any other CSS-only method which can support most browsers?

Thanks.
*PS - Pardon me I cant elegantly put this to you.*

Comment: if I understand correctly, you're referring to how "fixed" footers occupy 10% (or whatever the footer height is) of the full screen sections?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with using 90% instead of 100% min-height? Have a look at my code:

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color:#FFF
}

.fullsection {
    height:90%;
    background:red;
}

.b { background:blue; }

.extra { height: 10%; }

footer {
    height:10%;
    background:black;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullsection">A</div>
<div class="fullsection b">B</div>
<div class="extra"></div>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Each fullscreen section is 90% of page height and the footer is fixed at the bottom with 10% height. I have also added an empty "extra" div for the footer to rest at when you reach the bottom of page.

Comment: What if you put an image tag inside those divs. Then it becomes tricky to fill the image exactly as the dimensions of the div as now you are specifying height/width by percentages. If its a `background-image`, no problem, but with an `img tag`, then what?

Comment: How so? you can set the `img` tag to have a height and width of 100% so it will stretch to its container, this might cause weird stretching that can be solved by either going the background-cover way or by forcing an aspect ratio and hiding the sides with `overflow:hidden`... see: http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/00o5aw61/3/

Comment: Yes that works, but the image gets clipped. If we were using the `background-image` property, we could set the size to contain. It will show the entire image. But with `image` tag, is there anything like that. Later to align it center or left or right is easy. I found that using `vh` units, its possible. But thats too restrictive in browser support. see - http://jsfiddle.net/00o5aw61/6/

Comment: You can do the same without using `vh` units with the following: `height:100%; width:auto;` but there is still whitespace around the images... one trick is to "fade" the image to a solid color, this works well the image you used, setting a black background to the parent div will create an illusion that the image is fullwidth, see: http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/00o5aw61/8/

Comment: I tried using the percentage method for a layout. Alas, cant get it working - http://stackoverflow.com/q/33350011/4854499

Answer (score 0):

## display: flex

```css
#viewport {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: #ddd;
}
.footer {
  flex-basis: 10%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">

  <div class="content">

  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</div>
```

## height: 90%/10%

```css
#viewport {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 90%;
  background: #ddd;
}
.footer {
  height: 10%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="viewport">

  <div class="content">

  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</div>
```