# CSS Layouts 101 - getting confused in structuring layout

Tags: html, css, layout

For this layout, the easiest structuring method I can find with pure css is by using the `vh` unit.

Since its a bit restrictive in its support and the requirement being to go with only CSS, I am having a hard time working with the percentage method properly.

Target layout
[image]

I can only get full-screen cover image, section 1 and section 2 right.
Issues -
1. Footer is aligning over and bottom of the cover image.
2. Any text in Section 3 gets filled in between spaces in Section 2. (strange?)

From my analysis

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

is the culprit. Removing this, allows to achieve the target layout but the designing and styling is lost.

I am having lots of images in Section 2 aligned in grid, displayed preserving aspect ratio.

**Question is two fold** -
1. Possible proper css code
2. Why it happened and how to master the percentage method of styling.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1bpfdt5/
*(Using Bootstraps Sticky Footer reference structure)*

Thanks.
*PS - No Javascript*

Comment: Height 100% works relative to the parent's height, now the browser window's height. Have you tried any of these for the full-screen background? https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Ofcourse I have tried a lot of tricks. Strangely something I am not doing correctly. If built a structure like this, something goes wrong. The problem is I need to have that "Section 2" like portion, as displayed in the fiddle. That also utilizes the `100%` setting. But it is becoming a problem.

Comment: Looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/TylerH/e1bpfdt5/1/ Your document is a bit too complex at this point to address; you need to handle this kind of layout issue from the beginning.

Comment: @phenomenon is the footer sticky? the sections have any special behavior?

Comment: @TylerH Hey the layout is pretty close. Only the image needs to be adjusted as was before.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is what you are looking for:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
body {
  padding-top: 100vh;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1000;
}
footer {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
section {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">cover</div>

<section>
  section 1
  <br/>section 1
  <br/>section 1
  <br/>section 1
  <br/>section 1
  <br/>section 1
  <br/>section 1
  <br/>
</section>

<section>
  section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>section 2
  <br/>
</section>

<section>
  section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>section 3
  <br/>
</section>

<footer>footer</footer>
```

Comment: Footer is supposed to stay at the bottom of the page. Not fixed. Should appear after all other sections.

Comment: @phenomenon is that what you were looking for? the problem is solved?